# Why my single page htaccess redirect does't work?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Could You help me to fix my htaccess file for page homestack.pl? I have a problem with redirect page homestack.pl/categories to homestack.pl/kategorie. Thanks in advance.

Bug line added by me: RedirectMatch 301 /categories /kategorie
I results I have too many redirections, and page does't open.

```html
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RedirectMatch 301 /categories /kategorie
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I wold like to redirect
https://homestack.pl/categories
to
https://homestack.pl/kategorie
i was trying to add
RewriteRule ^/categories https://homestack.pl/kategorie [L,R=301]
but it still don't work

Comment: only this work
RewriteRule ^(.*)categories(.*)$ /$1kategorie$2 [L,R=301]
but this will replace those words in all urls.

Comment: Could anyone help me to solve the issue?